# Recursion problem in trees + python

Tags: python

I would like to mention that this is a homework but am not asking for help related to code.

I am having this strange problem . I am trying to implement a btree deletion and am having some recursive return problem

```
def delete ( tree , node , value ) :
     if node.leaf == True:
          # delete value from node 
          return tree

     elif node.leaf == False and value in node:
           # do other stuff

     else :
          delete(tree,node.Child,value)
          #recurse till you find leaf node
```

This is just a pseudo code as I can't post my entire code here. The problem coming is that

when I write `delete(Tree,Tree.root,value)` it runs first time recurses and executes the leaf node portion but returns me a None value.

I have checked out everything and even printed stuff just above the `return tree` statement and it is fine with tree having some value up till there.

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong in this recursive function....

Thanks a lot..

Comment: `node.leaf = False` looks shady. You should use `if node.leaf`/`if not node.leaf` instead to avoid these potential typos.

Comment: if you don't paste a working, runnable code it's difficult to say where the problem is.

Comment: Also, the `node.leaf == False` check at `elif` is redundant - this is implicit due to the first `if` check, i.e. just write `elif value in node:`.

Comment: To add to Oben Sonne's advice, Python recommends to use `if` instead of `elif` in this case since the `else` component isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick guess, fix to to:

```
 ...
 else:
      return delete(tree,node.Child,value) # you missed the return here
 ...
```

And I guess you should recurse into *all* children of the node, not only one (there might be more than one, right?).